# Can't find Abort method in Thread

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I'm porting a project to .NET Core and have some logic with the method. Do you know .NET Core supports `Abort()` method in Thread class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core equivalent to Thread.Abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465551/net-core-equivalent-to-thread-abort)

Answer (score 9):

Thread.Abort has been removed in .NET Core.

- Move Thread.Abort under FEATURE_LEGACYSURFACE https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/2342
- Never call Thread.Abort https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/726
- for tests purpose the custom [Abort](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/tests/src/baseservices/threading/regressions/threadex.cs) Ext method is used

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have understood so far it is now recommended to use CancellationToken. Please read more about how to use this here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx